# Convert row and column data to column-only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm completely new to Google Script so bear with me. I'm attempting to write a script that will take data from several rows and columns and then rewrite it into a single column with spacing.

so row

1a 1b 1c

2a 2b 2c

3a 3b 3c

will become...

1a

1b

1c

2a

2b

2c

etc...

I don't really have anything so far. I don't understand how each different piece of data is being accessed in the array. Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

```
function copyRow(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var numRows = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var rowIdx = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  sheet.getRange(rowIdx, 1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  for(var i = 0; i < numRows; i++){

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.  The `getValues()` method gets a 2 dimensional array.  Every inner array is a new row.  Every element of each inner array is a cell in a new column.  The 2D array can be collapsed into a regular array, with no outer array.  But to write the values, a 2D array is needed, so the code below creates a new 2D array.  Every inner array only has one value.

```
function copyRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var rowIdx = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  Logger.log('rowIdx: ' + rowIdx);

  //getRange(start row, start column, number of rows, number of columns)
  var theValues = sheet.getRange(rowIdx,1,sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  Logger.log('theValues.length: ' + theValues.length);

  theValues = theValues.toString().split(",");//convert 2D array to 1D
  Logger.log('theValues.length: ' + theValues.length);

  var outerArray = [];

  for(var i=0; i<theValues.length; i++){
    Logger.log('theValues[i]: ' + theValues[i]);
    outerArray.push(theValues[i]);
  };

  Logger.log('outerArray.length: ' + outerArray.length);
  sheet.getRange(1,1,outerArray.length,outerArray[0].length).setValues(outerArray);
};
```

Try it and see if it works, and let me know.

Comment: Hi Sandy thanks for the response, I'm getting an error  Cannot find method getRange(number,number,number). (line 7, file "Code")

Comment: See updated answer.  Change lines to this:  `var ss =spreadsheetApp.getActive();var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();`

Comment: Fixed arror by changing sheet.getRange to sheet.getActiveSheet().getRange. Have a new error now Cannot convert Array to Object in the last line.

Comment: `Sheet` had an upper case `S`.  Change to `sheet` and see if that works.

Comment: Fixed that, giving me the error cannot convert array to object.

Comment: See updated answer.  Add `Logger.log()` statements, run the code, and VIEW the LOGS.  Look for unexpected results.

Comment: Array looks good, just a list of names which is good. I think it has something to do with .setValues(outArray). Error is: Cannot convert Array to Object[][]. (line 20, file "Code"). Is it because outerArray is one dimensional and setValues is expecting a 2D array?

Comment: Change the last, 4th parameter from `1` to `outerArray[0].length`:  Change to: `sheet.getRange(1,1,outerArray.length,outerArray[0].length).setValues(outerArray);`  Are there any rows with empty cells?

Comment: Changed .setValues to .setValue run now. Still need to test to see if it works how I need it too. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If this answers you question, you can mark it as correct by clicking the big green check mark.

Comment: It's close but doesn't work quite right. Changing .setValues to .setValue only copies the first element in the array. Leaving .setValues continues to give me an error.

Comment: If you check the final array:  `Logger.log('outerArray: ' + outerArray);`  Does it look like it should?  Everything in there?  Add that after the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need script. Just put this formula in a cell:

```
=transpose(split(join(" ",A1:A3)," "))
```

You can join multiple rows and columns. I tested this on data like you provided in column A & B rows 1 to 3. Works fine.

```
=transpose(split(join(" ",A1:A3,B1:B3)," "))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I need to be able to grab several rows and columns at a time. I can only seem to  get this to work with one row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. Manually iterates through the array and sets it with a for loop.

```
 function copyRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var rowIdx = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var colIdx = sheet.getActiveRange().getColumnIndex();

  var theValues = sheet.getRange(rowIdx,colIdx,sheet.getLastRow(),3).getValues();

  theValues = theValues.toString().split(",");//convert 2D array to 1D

  var outerArray = [];

  for(var i=0; i<theValues.length; i++){
    outerArray.push(theValues[i]);
  };
Logger.log(outerArray);

//  sheet.getRange(1,1,outerArray.length,30).setValues(outerArray);

  for(var i = 0; i < outerArray.length; i++){
    sheet.getRange(30 + i, 1).setValue(outerArray[i]);
  }
};
```