# Get selected values in row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image: 1]

I want to be able to select a row and get the  values in it. I have:

```
var id = ' ------gkqlDoUg'

 var sheet =    SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName('mysheeet')
 var vals= sheet.getActiveRange().getValues();

 Logger.log(vals)
```

when I run this there are no errors but I see:

```
[20-08-08 13:08:17:834 PDT] [[ ]]
```

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something wrong, maybe a bug, but this fails randomly. Anyway here is a super simple demo of about "how to get this working"

1. Create a spreadsheet
2. Add some values to a row
3. Select the row
4. The following script to a bounded project to the previous spreadsheet

   ```
   function myFunction() {
     var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValues();
     Logger.log(values);
   }
   ```
5. Authorize the script
6. Run the function.

[image]

```
[20-08-08 15:58:57:727 CDT] [[adfa, afdfafs, dasfasf, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ]]
```

[image]

---

I think that there is a bug related to use chaining with `getActiveRange()`.

This sometime fails to get the expected result

```
function myFunction2(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var values = sheet.getActiveRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(values);
}
```

NOTE: The following snapshots were taken from the script's executions page.

Failed
[image: Fail]

Succeded
[image: Success]

This gets the expected result

```
function myFunction3(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  Logger.log(values);
}
```

Related

The following are questions that uses Class Sheet `getActiveRange()` chained with some Class Range methods like `getRow()`, `getValues()` but the current answers doesn't mention the cause of the problem, they just offer an alternative code

- [Emailing data from a spreadsheet at a specific time of day](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15012446/1595451)
- [Convert row and column data to column-only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35611508/1595451)
- [Trying to copy values from another tab but keep getting error "function getValues() can not be used as the left-hand side"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58661595/1595451)

Comment: you showed screenshots of functions failing and suceeding above. where is that from?

Comment: @user1592380 Those screen shots come from the script execution page. On the script editor click on View > Executions. Also this page could be accessed navigating from https://script.google.com

Answer (score 2):

You can select a specific row (in this case 68) as follows:

```
var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('mysheeet')
var target_row = 68;
var vals= sheet.getRange(target_row,1,1,sheet.getMaxColumns()).getValues().flat([1]);
```

The [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method can be omitted. I am using it in case you want the array to be 1 dimensional.

---

If you want to use **getActiveRange()** use **SpreadsheetApp.getActive()** instead :

```
var sheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('mysheeet')
var vals= sheet.getActiveRange().getValues();
```

and make sure that you **select** the entire row like you do in the screenshot.
In your example, I think you are not referencing to the correct spreadsheet file.

Comment: Have you tested the use of `getActiveRange().getValues()`?

Comment: @Rubén I see you replicated my second approach in your answer. Why would you do that?

Comment: "Your second approach" actually super close to the OP approach. I doesn't work for the OP and doesn't work to me either. Does it work for you?

Comment: It is not even close. There is a fundamental difference which is getting the active spreadsheet. There is a high chance that the OP made a mistake when referencing the spreadsheet id. So the getActive()/getActiveSpreadsheet() is a fundamental difference to OP's approach. Unfortunately, I will have to flag your answer.

Comment: @MariosKaramanis - I would take Rubén's side here, not sure where the second approach is replicated - in fact, it is indeed likely that the OP suffered from a bug, and it was referenced as such. Btw, do visit us in the [community chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217630/google-apps-script-chat-community), I see you are becoming active in the tag

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`Logger.log(vals[0].join(','));`