# Why Class Range getValues sometimes returns [[]] when chained to Class Sheet getActiveRange?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, method-chaining

Tl;Dr. Is a good practice chaining `getValues()` to Class Sheet `getActiveRange()` ? What could cause that sometimes returns `[[]]` instead of the expected values?

NOTE: `[[]]` is what is being displayed in the Log / Script executions page. These "things" doesn't show quotation characters for strings.

---

This is derived from [Get selected values in row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63319808/1595451)  where I posted an answer with a couple of alternatives to get the values of the active range.

Here I'm specifically asking for the reasons of the randomly failure of the following code

```
function myFunction2(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var values = sheet.getActiveRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(values);
}
```

Steps that I followed when the failure ocurred

1. Create a new spreadsheet
2. Add some values to a row
3. Select the row
   Click on the corresponding row heading
   [image]
4. Click on Tools > Script editor
   This creates a bounded project that uses the new runtime (Chrome V8) a default Google Cloud Project for Google Apps Script
5. Add a simple function:

```
function myFunction() {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(values);
}
```

5. Run myFunction to authorize the script
6. Run myFunction to actually execute myFunction
7. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the Log
8. Add the referred function at the beginning of this question (`myFunction2`)
9. Run `myFunction2`
10. Open the Log using the referred keyboard shortcut (step 7)
    `[[]]` were logged instead of the expected values.

[image]

11. Add a third function

```
function myFunction3(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  Logger.log(values);
}
```

12. Run `myFunction3`
13. Open the Log using the referred keyboard shortcut
14. Run again `myFunction2`
15. Open the Log using the referred keyboard shortcut (step 7).
    Now the expected values were logged.

[image]

The following are questions that use Class Sheet `getActiveRange()` chained with some Class Range methods like `getRow()`, `getValues()` but the current answers doesn't mention the cause of the problem, they just offer an alternative code

- [Emailing data from a spreadsheet at a specific time of day](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15012446/1595451)
- [Convert row and column data to column-only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35611508/1595451)
- [Trying to copy values from another tab but keep getting error "function getValues() can not be used as the left-hand side"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58661595/1595451)

I already searched the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640%20status:open). While there are some issues related to getActiveRange like [Calls to .getActiveRange() don't return correct cells as seen in filter views](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36762085), [getActiveRange() incorrect in onChange trigger for some column/row operations](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38159142), etc., they don't appear to be directly related to this issue.

---

As of Aug, 9, 2020 (UTC) the same spreadsheet / bounded script are returning the expected values, anyway I added another funtion to test  `getValues()`, `getRow()`, `getColumn()`, `getA1Notation()` and `getGridI()`. All returned the expected values.

I just found another question about a similar problem with `getActiveRange()` -> [getActiveRange not returning current selection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54032056/1595451). This question is not a duplicate because that question only mentions that after 24hours it worked again but didn't mentions if it's a a good practice to chain Class Range methods to `getActiveRange()` and the currents answers doesn't explains why this happens.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219522/discussion-on-question-by-ruben-why-class-range-getvalues-sometimes-returns).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61541548

Answer (score 0):

So far my conclusion based on the comments to the question and on the related questions that used chaining and the answers uses equivalent code but that doesn't use chaining I think that is safer to avoid the use of chaining with "active" methods.

By active methods I mean

- Class Spreadsheet `getActiveSheet()`
- Class Spreadsheet and Class Sheet `getActiveRange()`

Related chat rooms

- [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219469/discussion-between-ruben-and-oleg-valter) created by me
- [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219520/discussion-between-oleg-valter-and-themaster) created by Oleg Valter
- [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219522/discussion-on-question-by-ruben-why-class-range-getvalues-sometimes-returns) created by a ♦ mod.